# Regex - Find javascript methods and its variables in text

Tags: java, regex, methods

Best Solution i come up with so far, given a textblock it finds those methods that have paramters, but also the function with parameter key like this: "get: function(key)".

```
    public class JavaScriptMethodFinder
{
    static readonly string pattern = @"(?<=\s(?<Begin>[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*?)\(|\G)\s*((['""]).+?(?<!\\)\2|\{[^}]+\}|[^,;'""(){}\)]+)\s*(?:,|(?<IsEnd>\)))";
    private static readonly Regex RegEx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Find(string text)
    {
        var t = RegEx.Matches(text);
        dynamic current = null;
        bool isBegin;
        foreach (Match item in t)
        {

            if (isBegin = (item.Groups["Begin"].Value != string.Empty))
            {
                current = new ExpandoObject();
                current.MethodName = item.Groups["Begin"].Value;
                current.Parameters = new List<string>();
                current.Parameters.Add(item.Groups[1].Value);
            }else
                current.Parameters.Add(item.Groups[1].Value);
            if (item.Groups["IsEnd"].Value != string.Empty)
            {
                isBegin = false;
                if(!(item.Groups["Begin"].Value != string.Empty))
                    current.Parameters.Add(item.Groups[1].Value);
                yield return current;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I wanna find Methods and its Variables. Given two examples.

#### First Example

```
function loadMarkers(markers)
{
     markers.push(
            new Marker(
              "Hdsf", 
              40.261330438503,
              10.4877055287361,
              "some text"
            ) 
      );
}
```

#### Second Example

```
var block = new AnotherMethod('literal', 'literal', {"key":0,"key":14962,"key":false,"key":2});
```

So far i have, tested here: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

```
(?<=Marker\(|\G)\s*((?<name>['""]).+?(?<!\\)\2|\{[^}]+\}|[^,;'""(){}\)]+)\s*(?:,|\))
```

Found 5 matches:
                  "Hdsf", has 2 groups:
"Hdsf"
"
                    40.261330438503, has 2 groups:
40.261330438503
                  10.4877055287361, has 2 groups:
10.4877055287361
                  "some text"                 ) has 2 groups:
"some text"
"
            ) has 2 groups:

```
(?<=AnotherMethod\(|\G)\s*((?<name>['""]).+?(?<!\\)\2|\{[^}]+\}|[^,;'""(){}\)]+)\s*(?:,|\))
```

Found 3 matches:
'literal', has 2 groups:
'literal'
' (name)
 'literal', has 2 groups:
'literal'
' (name)
 {"key":0,"key":14962,"key":false,"key":2}) has 2 groups:
{"key":0,"key":14962,"key":false,"key":2}
 (name)

I would like to combine it such that i have one expression

- Match<(methodname)>

  - Group : parameter
  - Group : parameter
  - Group : parameter
- Match<(methodname)>

  - Group : parameter
  - Group : parameter
  - Group : parameter

so when i scan a page which contains both cases, i will get two matches witch 
ect the first capture being the method name and then the following is the paramters.

I been trying to modify what i already have, but its to complex with the LookBehind stuff for I to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex's are a very problematic approach for this type of project. Have you looked at using a genuine JavaScript parser/compiler like [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/overview.html)? That will give you full awareness of JavaScript syntax "for free" and the ability to walk your source code meaningfully.

Comment: Its for scrapping a few html pages. I would prefer a regex solution rather then using a external lib.